# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'buttonset'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try set/change standart radio buttons to jquery (looks like a button)
But in some page works fine but now i have probem:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'buttonset' 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function(){$("#new1").buttonset()
});
});
</script>
```

and my body part is:

```
<body>
<div id="new1">
<input type="radio" id="return1" name="radio"><label for="return1">Name</label>
<input type="radio" id="return2" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="return2">Surname</label>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is `buttonset`? `buttonset` from jQuery UI? Does you add jQuery UI to your page?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

Comment: @Pinal i did becouse another functions work fine

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/qJn2U/ all works, add jQuery 1.11 and 1.8 UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input:radio[name=radio]").click(function(){
      var value = $(this).attr("id");
      alert(value);
})
});
</script>
```

**Note:**
`The button widget was added in jQuery UI 1.8, it's not part of 1.7. Make sure you have updated version.`

Comment: which version of Jquery you are using ?

Comment: <script src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

Comment: i have 1.11 both versions jquery and jquery iu

Comment: its vork return return1 and return2 but not animated (not like a block or button)

Comment: animated ? what type of animation

Comment: please look at my post and Pinal post above. radios looks like a button